# how to convert binary data into string format in j2me

Tags: encoding, java-me, compression

I am using the gzip algorithm in j2me. After compressing the string I tried to send the compressed string as text message but the size was increasing drastically. So I used base64 encoding to convert the compressed binary to text. But while encoding the size is still increasing, please help me with an encoding technique which when used the data size remains the same.

I tried sending binary sms but as its limit is 134 characters I want to compress it before sending the sms.

Answer (score 0):

You have some competing requirements here.
The fact you're considering using SMS as a transport mechanism makes me suspect that the data you have to send is quite short to start with.
Compression algorithms (in general) work best with large amounts of data and can end up creating a longer output than you started with if you start with something very short.

There are very few useful encoding changes that will leave you with output the same length as when you started. (I'm struggling to think of anything really useful right now.)

You may want to consider alternative transmission methods or alternatives to the compression techniques you have tried.